# How do i know when a batch of messages is consumed in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I hava a producer that gets batches of items to put into the queue. I'd like to know when all items of a batch are consumed. It doesn't matter wheter this is handled in the producer or the consumer.

The best I can think of is to include the total batch size and an incrementing number per batch in the messages. This way the consumer knows when it's handling the last message.

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe something RabbitMQ offers out of the box?

I'm using [spring-cloud-stream](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream#overview) and would like to keep it, but using the rabbitmq java libs directly is an option.

Update:

- It's only when all items of a batch are consumed, that the batch is marked as finished.
- A batch can sonsist of 100'000 items. The idea is to have a scaling number of parallel consumers to process them. So sending all at once is no option.

Comment: It does not provided by design of RabbitMQ, so all possible answers are workarounds. What if this is an X-Y problem?  Why do you need to know about batch processing finish? Maybe you can send all this data in a single message?

Comment: What is a X-Y problem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: Did you figure out a pattern to implement this? I’m trying to do the same and checking queue length after consuming each message doesn’t seem like a good way to do this.....

Comment: We ended up numbering the messages and sending a reply in a second queue. This way the sender can do it's own bookkeeping. If some messages are missing after a timeout an error is raised.